# Expecting the right calling context (this) in the JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Consider this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    myObj.init();
};

var myObj = {
    init: function () {
        console.log("init: Let's call the callMe method...");

        //callMe is not defined...
        callMe();

        //Works fine!
        this.callMe();
    },

    callMe: function () {
        console.log('callMe');
    }
};
```

Since the init function gets called this way (myObj.init), I expect `this` to be myObj in the init function. And if that is the case, why the `callMe` function fails? How am I supposed to call the `callMe` function without using the this context in the init body? (Actually, it's too annoying to call the object methods using `this` over and over again through the functions. So what's the point of having a single object?)

I would like to know how can I fix this so that the callMe method gets called using the first invocation in the code above?

Comment: JavaScript is not like "other languages" because it's scripting language thus has some basic limitations. Object in JavaScript is not really an object, it's more like array that can have functions as its items. Want proof? http://jsfiddle.net/MeFXf/ So, I fear you'll have to follow Mr. Crowder's advice and *just get used to typing this*

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: You example is misleading. Objects are not arrays. Arrays are objects!

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: *"Object in JavaScript is not really an object"* Sure it is. All that fiddle shows is that arrays in JavaScript are objects. (Which they are. In fact, they're not *arrays*, but that's neither here nor there...) JavaScript's objects are true objects. They're just incredibly open and flexible ones.

Comment: @Felix, @T.J. Thanks, I stand corrected.. they are objects but as the `this` issue demonstrates, different objects than in languages like C# or Java where the `this` is not required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is never implicit in JavaScript as it is in some other languages. Although there are ways to do it, like this using the `with` statement:

```
init: function () {
    console.log("init: Let's call the callMe method...");

    // Make `this` implicit (SEE BELOW, not recommended)
    with (this) {
        // Works
        callMe();
    }
},
```

...it's generally a **bad idea**. Douglas Crockford probably wrote one of the better descriptions of *why* it's a bad idea, which you can find [here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/). Basically, using `with` makes it nearly impossible to tell what the code's going to do (and slows the code down, if you do *anything else* in that `with` statement that doesn't come from the `this` object).

This isn't the only way that JavaScript's `this` is not the same as it is in some other languages. In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where the function is *defined*. When you do `this.callMe()` (or the equivalent `this["callMe"]()`, or of course `foo.callMe()`, etc.), **two** things happen: The function reference is retrieved from the property, and the function is called in a special way to set `this` to be the object that property came from. If you don't call a function through a property that way, the call doesn't set any particular `this` value and you get the default (which is the global object; `window` on browsers). It's the act of making the call that sets what `this` is. I've explored this in depth in a couple of articles on my blog, [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html).

This (no pun) can be made even clearer if you look at JavaScript's `call` and `apply` functions, which are available on all function objects. If I do this:

```
callMe.call({});
```

...it'll call the `callMe` function with a blank object (`{}`) as `this`.

So basically, just get used to typing `this`. :-) It's still useful to have properties and methods associated with an object, even without the syntactic convenience (and confusion!) of an implicit `this`.

Comment: Very nice explanation! `with` is really evil (and i _never_ used it). +1!

Comment: Well, so what's the point of grouping those methods into a given object if I've to type this over and over again? Actually, the typing isn't the problem. The problem is that I've to watch for the closures and some other areas. So it ends up having a "me" local variable pointing to this, and then calling the member methods (or whatever they are called under JS) on the "me" context. This actually increases the code size and makes it complicated. I'm really wondered if it's not addressed by a given framework yet...

Comment: @J Rattz: I think there's a lot of value in organizing data into objects, even if you have to specify the object expressly. Yes, with closures and such, you do have to assign to a var the closure closes over (I see `self` used a lot; `me` is good; perhaps `t`?), but the flexibility that JavaScript's functions provide more than makes up for it in my book. In terms of code size, throw a [minifier](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) or even the [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler) at it. (Of course, that doesn't help if you're *already* doing that.) :-)

Comment: @J Rattz: (I don't mean to pummel you with information. :-) ) Re *"I'm really wondered if it's not addressed by a given framework yet"* The thing is, it would be expensive at runtime. You'd basically have to make each function a wrapper around a function that then called the original with a particular `this` value. In fact, the two popular frameworks jQuery and Prototype both offer features for that [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and [here](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/). But using a closure directly, as you suggested, is much more efficient.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: We have weird problems, don't we? ;) This was the first that came to my mind when i read your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the module pattern, which captures all private variables inside a closure, so you are free to use them without `this`, **as they're in the same scope**. You then pick and choose which methods/variables you want to make public:

```
var myObj = (function () {
   var init = function () {
      callMe(); // This now works
   };

   var callMe = function () {
      ...
   };

   // Now choose your public methods (they can even be renamed):
   return {
      init: init, // Same name
      callMyName: callMe // Different name
   };
}) ();
```

Now:

```
myObj.init(); // Works
myObj.callMyName(); // Works
myObj.callMe(); // Error
```

Comment: Yeah, for his specific example, since it's just a single object and not a constructor function, that would work. It doesn't generalize well once you're doing the constructor function, though, because you end up replicating functions (in memory, not in the source) for every instance, which starts being expensive -- you lose the prototypical benefit. (Don't get me wrong, I love the module pattern and use it all the time to let my "classes" [constructor functions] share data and have private functions available to instances. I just don't do it at the *instance* level.)

Comment: @T.J Crowder: I'm not pummeled, but I'm confused a little bit when I saw the box9's answer, the "module pattern". I'm just trying to figure it out once and forever. So, it'd be highly appreciated if you tell me how does the context gets resolved by the JS Engine. Is it all because of the myObj.init() line that the JS Engine decides what context it's going to be used? Please explain this more. Really thanks. I actually thought that calling myFunc function without specifying its context simply means calling it on the window object, but obviously, I was wrong. Would you please explain this more?

Comment: @J Rattz: No problem. :-) [This post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) on my blog may help; I go into scope in there a fair bit. Scope in JavaScript is object-oriented. When you call a function, an object is created for that call, which has properties on it for all of that function's arguments, `var` s, and contained function declarations. That object is put at the top of the "scope chain", so a free reference to a symbol (`callMe`, for instance) will be checked against that object first. If there's a matching property...(cont'd)

Comment: @J Rattz: (continuing) ...that property value is used; if there's no matching property, the next scope object in the chain (the one for the call to the containing context) is checked; and so on. At the global execution context, this scope object *is* the `window` object (which is unusual; all of the others are completely anonymous). The key here is that the scope object (more properly the *variable object* for the *execution context* for the call to the function) is *per call*. In box9's example above, there's an anonymous wrapper function that creates an execution context...(cont'd)

Comment: @J Rattz: (continuing) ...and therefore a variable object (scope object) which contains both `init` and `callMe`. Then he returns an object which has a reference to `init` (in its `init` property) and `callMe` (in its `callMyName` property). Since both of those are closures over the scope object created by the call to the anonymous function, they both have access to the variable `callMe` contained by that scope object -- but nothing else does, it's entirely private. The scope object for that call lives as long as you retain a reference to the object the call returned. HTH!

Comment: @J Rattz: One last thing: One crucial thing about JavaScript that trips people up is that functions can be assigned to object properties, but they're not *methods* of objects. They're just functions. The first blog post I referred you do in my answer (http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) covers this. It's probably one of the biggest differences (and very liberating, once you "grok" it).